# Visual studio doesn't show output

Tags: visual-studio, output

What could be the problem? When press F5 the first time I got an warning from Avast, but i unchecked all the option that scan program while executing. But i still can't run the output. Please help me I need to make a school project.

[image]

Comment: Your output console is closing immediately when the program exits.

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless, as are pictures of your entire desktop. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.